# How can I autostart python in raspberry with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, autostart

I am writing a python program with tkinter in RPI. I want to Autostart this program on boot, but it keeps error on:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNAWW.png)
PS:I didn't using any matlab on this program.

Comment: This is very hard, you should make your script a service and then add that to the startup

Answer (score 0):

Raspbian? I just used the autostart file to do this. Edit `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and add:

```
@/home/pi/path/to/myprogram.py
```

Be sure to include a shebang in your file. Then set the executable bit with this command:

```
chmod +x /home/pi/path/to/myprogram.py
```

Edit: That error looks like you are trying to run your program remotely, via ssh or something. I don't think that error is related to the autostart. If you want to run the program via ssh, you need to type this command first:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Comment: Nope, I use a keyboard terminate RPI directly without using ssh.

Comment: That error code appear when adding in Autostart after rebooting

Comment: The GUI terminal emulator (Ctrl-Alt-T) or a different tty (Ctrl-Alt-F1)? If it's the terminal emulator then there's something very wrong with your OS installation. I'd do a clean install. A different tty is the same as remote access. In either case the display export should fix it.

Comment: But I just try the way you provide by using a keyboard directly connected to Rpi, but it just won't autostart after I reboot

Comment: @LimBrendan that makes me think you forgot the executable bit or the shebang. Otherwise I'm afraid I'd need to log into the RPi to troubleshoot it; sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
cd /home/pi/.config/autostart
```

Then create new file:

```
sudo nano pythonprogramm.desktop
```

(you can replace "pythonprogramm")

And you write this in the new file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=pythonprogramm
#Exec=sudo idle /var/www/html/pythonprogramm.py
Exec=sudo /var/www/html/pythonprogramm.py
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=yes
Hidden=false
```

Reboot and it should work :)